# Concatenating a variable multiple times in string in MySQL

Tags: mysql, concatenation, heidisql

**Scenario:** I am trying to set a string to a variable and then pass it to a prepared statement. I am using the "concat" function to create the string that will be passed.

**Query:**

```
set @floatvar := 'test1'    
set @random_var2 := concat('SELECT ', @floatvar, ' AS Fields, COUNT(CASE WHEN ', @floatvar, ' IS NULL THEN 1 END) AS NullCount');
```

**Obs:** My query has more parts to be included in the string, but even with only this I am already having trouble, so I doing it step by step.

**Issue:** When I try to run this, I get a syntax error (SQL Error 1064) on line 2. I have no idea why this is happening.

**Question:** What is causing this issue, and how could it be fixed?

Comment: semicolon is missing after `set @floatvar1 := 'test1'`

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Just added and it tested again, same issue.

Comment: I can still see syntax errors. It is unclear what you are trying to do here ?

Comment: You cannot start a statement with concat.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I am trying to concatenate a string into a variable, but am getting the syntax error.

Comment: @P.Salmon forgot to add that, will edit.

Comment: Your statement doesn't make sense you are attempting to select a column test1 but not from anywhere. your prepared statement looks like this - SELECT test1 AS Fields, COUNT(CASE WHEN test1 IS NULL THEN 1 END) AS NullCount and you get this ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'test1' in 'field list'

Comment: @P.Salmon As i wrote in the OP, my statement has other parts that will be passed. What I want to understand is why I am not being able to set this "concat" procedure into a variable, or why I am getting this syntax error. Once I fix that, I will add the other part and pass it.

Comment: You get the 1064 error when you execute the prepared statement you get a more helpful error if you copy and paste a select of random_var2. The set random_var2 works fine if you terminate the previous statement.

Comment: @P.Salmon Yeah, that's my issue, the set random_var2 is not working for me, not even with the previous statement closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no **SELECT ..  INTO ..** like this:

```
SELECT 
 concat('SELECT ', @floatvar, ' AS Fields, COUNT(CASE WHEN ', @floatvar, ' IS NULL THEN 1 END) AS NullCount')
INTO @myquery;
```

**Sample**

```
MariaDB [test]> SET @floatvar := 'test1'    ;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.002 sec)

MariaDB [test]> SELECT
    ->  concat('SELECT ', @floatvar, ' AS Fields, COUNT(CASE WHEN ', @floatvar, ' IS NULL THEN 1 END) AS NullCount')
    -> INTO @myquery;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [test]>
MariaDB [test]> SELECT @myquery;
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| @myquery                                                                       |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| SELECT test1 AS Fields, COUNT(CASE WHEN test1 IS NULL THEN 1 END) AS NullCount |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [test]>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just tried it. If I try to set a value to floatvar ('test' for example) I get the same error as before.

Comment: @DGMS89 - I have add a sample in my answer without any error

Answer (score 1):

```
set @floatvar := 'test1' ;

set @random_var2 := (select concat('SELECT ', @floatvar, ' AS Fields, COUNT(CASE WHEN ', @floatvar, ' IS NULL THEN 1 END) AS NullCount'));

select @random_var2;
```

gives this

```
SELECT test1 AS Fields, COUNT(CASE WHEN test1 IS NULL THEN 1 END) AS NullCount;
```

Results in

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'test1' in 'field list'
```

If you do this

```
prepare sqlstmt = @random_var2;
execute sqlstmt;
deallocte prepare sq;stmt;
```

result

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '= @random_var2' at line 1
```

Its best to check the prepared statement works before firing into dynamic sql because the error messages from dynamic sql may not be helpful.